# Plinq Aggregate extension with StringBuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, plinq

I've made some experimental Plinq query, and I'm not sure about the result can be corrupted or not.

Here is 3 different method, which provides the same result:

```
// unitTask is typeof Task<List<SomeEntity>>

        //sequential version PLINQ
        Console.WriteLine(unitTask.Result.Take(10)
           .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
           (text, current) => text.AppendFormat("@{0}sa{1}", 
               current.FullName.Substring(0, 3), 
               current.FullName.Substring(4)))
           .ToString());

        //parallel version PLINQ
        Console.WriteLine(unitTask.Result.Take(10).AsParallel()
            .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
            (text, current) => text.AppendFormat("@{0}sa{1}",
                current.FullName.Substring(0, 3),
                current.FullName.Substring(4)))
            .ToString());

        //parallel version foreach with Partitioner
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(unitTask.Result.Take(10)), r =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            output.AppendFormat("@{0}sa{1}", r.FullName.Substring(0, 3), 
                r.FullName.Substring(4));
        });

        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

My questions are:

Can I use `StringBuilder` in PLINQ? 
Due to append method is not thread safe as I know.

Or does it run in sequential mode in this case?

Parallel.Foreach runs the query in different threads, but result is the same as sequential Plinq.

Is it accidental, or it's smart and uses some synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This version doesn't use PLINQ, it uses the standard LINQ, so it's safe.
2. This version uses an overload of `Aggregate()` that's not safely parallelizable, so it will also execute on a single thread. This means it's safe, but it also won't be any faster than the sequential version.

   To actually take advantage of PLINQ, you would need to use [another overload of `Aggregate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384149) that actually can execute in parallel. In your case that would mean having a separate `StringBuilder` for each thread and then combine all the `StringBuilder`s into one. Something like:

   ```
   input.AsParallel().Aggregate(
       () => new StringBuilder(),
       (text, current) => text.AppendFormat("@{0}", current.FullName),
       (text1, text2) => text1.Append(text2),
       text => text.ToString())
   ```

   This assumes that you don't care about the order of elements in the final string. If you do, this code won't work correctly.
3. This code modifies the same `StringBuilder` object from multiple threads. `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe, so this code is not safe.

Comment: After further investigation, and measuring, I've got similar results (single thread and slower than pure sequential linq). Thanks for confirmation, and the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's accidental, probably because the code doesn't do all that much and may be running on a single thread. All your calls involde `unitTask.Result` which blocks until `unitTask` finishes. All snippets actually work on only 10 entities produced sequentially, so there is not enough data to justify parallel execution

The three snippets do different things:

1. The first snippet simply processes a list of 10 snippets sequentially.
2. The PLINQ version takes a list of 10 entities but doesn't do anything in parallel. Even if it did, the call to `Aggregate` collects the results from all workers and processes them sequentially to create the final result.
3. The third snippet *could* display parallel behavior, as it executes an action block in parallel. Again, the number of results is too small and only one thread is used

Comment: Third snippet uses 4 threads for me. Simple string object is better choice in this case?

Comment: What I meant was that you are comparing different things. This isn't about thread safety. Even you concatenated strings, you would get inconsistent results because each thread would see a different input string at each iteration. What are you trying to solve anyway? If you want to log progress, Console.WriteLine is more than enough

Comment: as I wrote this is an experimental task, to understand how these component works. I don't want to solve anything. Just comparing sequential and parallel executions. So you say that it's not a good idea to concatenate string in parallel way.